# Don't understand reasons for error messages when trying to get elements of matrix

Tags: matrix, simplifying-expressions

I am trying to simplify the seemingly very complicated inverse of a 4x4 matrix. "Simplify" resulted in something only somewhat less complicated. So yesterday I started simplifying the elements one-by-one.  The matrix is "T," and I used "Inverse[T][[1, 1]]" through "Inverse[T][[1,4]]" to get these elements, and then Simplified these in turn. (It turned out that they are, in fact, quite simple.)

Today I tried to continue this with the second row. But "Inverse[T][[2,1]]" resulted in the message "Part 2 of Inverse[T] does not exist." I tried this on a simpler 4x4 matrix, R: "R[[2, 1]]" resulted in "Part specification R[[2,1]] is longer than depth of object." So then I tried "Inverse[T][[1, 1]]" again, and *today* I got that same error: "Inverse[T][[1,2]] is longer than depth of object."

What could be causing this?

Comment: it works for me on V 13.3.1  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAK6R.png)  **What could be causing this?** without an example, it is hard to say what is the problem. Did you try from clean kernel?  May be you have added `MatrixForm` ?? If so, try again without it. This is a wrapper and prevents evaluation. See  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gn2PN.png)

Comment: I think you are fooling yourself, it happens to all of us Try with a fresh kernel. Or then Inverse[T] is not what you assume.

Comment: Thank you Nasser and Daniel Huber for your responses.

Comment: Cont.: 1) Starting with a new kernel didn't help; 2) I wasn't using MatrixForm here; 3) I cleared all the variable definitions, regenerated the matrix inverse - designated "Tinv" - and successfully executed the command "Tinv[[2,1]]." But then "Tinv[[2,2]]" again resulted in "Part specification Tinv[[2,2]] is longer than depth of object." What should I try next?? 4) Daniel, you said "it happens to all of us." What did you mean by "it'? Thanks again, -Alan

Comment: Is there any chance that `T` is small and simple enough that you could edit your question and paste `T` as text, not a jpg, and follow that by the couple of lines of commands that you do to get the error, also as text? You can then test this to confirm you can scrape it off your screen and paste it into MMA and get the same error you are getting now. That should let other's see exactly what you've typed and duplicate exactly the error. Don't need to see the very complicated inverse, we need to be able to compute that. That may be the fastest way to find the answer for you.

Comment: Thank you Bill for your message. Let me make sure I understand what you're suggesting: I just searched for 'how to copy MMA code into Stack Exchange' and one of the answers was 'convert it to Raw Input Form and then copy and paste.' Doing this, the first entry - i.e., element [1,1] is below. The entire matrix is way to big to do this. Is there any other way? (2*e*f)/(a*(2*d + p) + Sqrt[a^2*(2*(d^2 + e^2) + 2*(d + e)*p + p^2) - 2*a^(3/2)*Sqrt[-4*b*e^2*f^2 + a*(d - e)^2*(d + e + p)^2]])

Comment: You have correctly formatted your code in your comment so I would easily be able to scrape-n-paste that into my notebook. 16 expressions that size would be too big to fit in a comment, but you could edit your question and append those 16 to the end, followed by the line you used to get the inverse and the line you used to try to extract a single item and that would not be terribly big, unless you have done other things in code more than that. AND all that would let us scrape it off the screen into our MMA and reproduce exactly what you had done, see the same error and tell you how to fix it

Comment: Thank you Bill. After my last message I discovered I could extract the _rows_ of the matrix without any problem, so I did that and proceeded to Simplify. So I'm going to table this problem - I continually encounter strange issues with MMA, and using workarounds - when they're available - is sufficient.